# How do I format form elements effectively without using a table?

Tags: html, css, format

I have been trying for several hours to format my form neatly without the use of a table.

I've floated the labels left and the inputs right but they still don't line up neatly with each other. Ideally it would look like so:

Label(Root Diameter) | Input(text) | label(mm)

I know I can do it using a table but I am looking for a more elegant and professional way of doing it. If someone could just point me in the right direction and perhaps give me an example I would appreciate it greatly.

Here is my code.

html:

```
<head>

    <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="criticalSpeedCalc.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="calcstyle.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div id="calcWrapper">
        <form name="calculator" id="calculator">
            <label class="type">Unit of Measurement:</label>
            <br>
            <select name="unit" class="input">
                <option value="120904000">Metric (cm)</option>
                <option value="4760000">Imperial (inches)</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <label class="type">Root Diameter:</label>
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="root" class="input" autocomplete="off">
            <label for="unit">mm</label>
            <br>
            <label class="type">Width between bearings:</label>
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="bearings" class="input" autocomplete="off">
            <label for="unit">mm</label>
            <br>
            <label class="type">End Fixity:</label>
            <br>
            <select name="fixity" class="input">
                <option value=".36">1</option>
                <option value="1.0">2</option>
                <option value="1.47">3</option>
                <option value="2.23">4</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <label class="type">Max Speed:</label>
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="speed" class="input" autocomplete="off">
            <label for="rpm">rpm</label>
            <br>
            <br>    <a href="#" id="reset" class="input" onclick="">Reset</a>
<a href="#" id="calculate" class="input" onclick="Calculate(); return(false);">Calculate</a>
<a href="#" id="close" class="input" onclick="">Exit</a>

        </form>
    </div>
</body>



#calcWrapper {

    background-image: url("Design1.png");

    width: 265px;

    height: 365px;

    float: left;

    /*border-width: 2px;
border-style: solid;*/

}
```

css:

```
#calculator {

    width: 186px;

    height: 230px;

    margin-left: 38px;

    margin-top: 115px;

    padding-left: 5px;

    font: bold 11px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

    text-align: center;

    -moz-box-sizing:content;

    /*border-width: 2px;
border-style: solid;*/

}



.input {

    margin: 1px;

    max-width: 80px;

    max-height: 10px;

    font: bold 10px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

    display: block;

    vertical-align:middle;

    margin-bottom: 10px;

    float: right;

}

select.input {

    max-height: 18px;

}

label.type {

    width: 80px;

    display: block;

    vertical-align:middle;

    float:left;

    clear:left;

    margin: 2px;

}
```

And here is a fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/3Ej7Q/)

Comment: Why not just use a table to do it?

Comment: I don`t understand why `<table>` is not elegant and **PROFESSIONAL** ??

Comment: My web development professor advises against it, and I feel like it's the lazy route.

Comment: I agree this isnt a tabular data and should not be in a table

Comment: That's what I saw most people saying when I was looking for a solution, so I assumed it was frowned upon or considered bad practice. Even if that's not the case, I am still interested in using the "proper" method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the solution to my problem which involved setting all the elements inside the form to display:inline-block, and setting the form's text-aligntment to justify.

For a better explanation than I am able to give give [this](http://adamschwartz.co/magic-of-css/chapters/2-layout/) a squiz. (The answer is in the text align section)

And [here](http://tinylink.net/a7afd) is a link to an updated fiddle

Hope I was able to help anyone in the same predicament.

Answer (score 1):

You can have "normal" html tags and table-like display using the [CSS Table Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#table-display)

Answer (score 1):

Since this is not a tabular data not using table is the right choice however you can use div elements to create a table :)

```
.table {
    display:table;
}
.table-row {
    display: table-row;
}
.table-cell {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3Ej7Q/3/

Comment: Isn't that kind of the same thing though?

Comment: No it is not, Tables are avoided cuz there semantic meaning is different but divs are best known for creating structure in your layout.
And it doesn't matter what class names you use and whether there display type is table or table cell in terms of search engines.

Answer (score 0):

You can just float your `.input` class to the `left` and make it a bit narrower (`max-width:70px`).

See it here: http://jsbin.com/pepixare/1/edit

Comment: That has made it look a lot better, thank you. Still looking weird in firefox though. I shall continue tweaking until I get it right.

Answer (score 0):

I use div's to solve this problem.
my width is in % you can use px if you prefer.

col- represents the width of the div in %.(col-40 == width:40%;)

you can easily implement this with other attributes like inputs,ul,ol,a,img ect.

```
<div class="table">
<div class="tr">
    <div class="th col-40 fl pd-l-2">monday</div>
    <div class="td col-2 fl">&#58;</div>
    <div class="td col-58 fr txt-alnC">09:30 - 18:00</div>
</div>
<div class="tr">
    <div class="th col-40 fl">tuesday</div>
    <div class="td col-2 fl">&#58;</div>
    <div class="td col-58 fr txt-alnC">09:30 - 18:00</div>
</div>
</div>

.table {
width: 100%;
float: left;
cursor: pointer;
```

}

```
.table .tr {
float:left;
width:100%;
height:40px;
```

}

```
.table .tr .th,
.table .tr .td {
height:47%;
padding:5% 0;
```

}